# Не понимаю фразу из объяснения про исключения

Tags: python

[The Python Tutorial: 8.6. Defining Clean-up Actions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

> The finally clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other
>   clause of the try statement is left via a break, continue or return
>   statement.

Что-то не понимаю, что тут имеется ввиду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Речь о том, что блок finally выполняется после блоков try и catch и выполняется он всегда, даже если не произошло никаких исключительных ситуаций, что отличает его от блока catch. Собственно, отсюда и его название.

Comment: Как бы это **питон**, т.е. используется _try/except_. И меня интересует, что тут имеется ввиду относительно использования try/except/finally при наличии операторов break, continue, return.

Comment: А пример, который там дальше приведён вам тоже не помог в понимании? Смысл в том, что вне зависимости от того, что произойдёт в остальных блоках: исключения, возврат значения, прерывание цикла и т.п., finally всегда будет выполнен.

Comment: Да понимаю я для чего блок _finally_! Меня интересует, что имеется ввиду относительно механизма _try/except/finally_ при наличии операторов **break**, **continue**, **return** внутри _try_

Comment: А я не понимаю, что вам непонятно. Из блока try можно выйти при помощи перечисленных операторов, что тут еще можно добавить?

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет вот этот пример: http://ideone.com/6MCoVZ ?